# Can't view JRebel Config Center

Tags: eclipse, jrebel

I have used JRebel and Eclipse Juno for some time, but now it seems broken. If I try to open the JRebel Config Centre or any other view related to JRebel I only get: *"JRebel Config Centre view can only be opened in the JRebel Config Centre perspective!"*

I don't know if it's related, but my license got obsolete last week and I replaced the old license file with a new one a few days ago. I know it worked before I updated the license I don't know though if it has worked afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not really sure what the problem was. But after the second uninstall/reinstall from the marketplace the problem dissapeared and everything is back to normal again.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options of getting to the Config Centre:

- Help -> JRebel Config Centre
- Open Perspective -> JRebel Config Centre

Comment: Yes, and when I do that I only get a blank white screen with the message: "JRebel Config Centre view can only be opened in the JRebel Config Centre perspective!"

Answer (score 0):

Will you please try below mentioned two options & let me know if you are able to view the config center?

1] Windows->Preferences->JRebel->Jrebel Config Center

2] Windows->Show View->Other->Jrebel Config Center

Comment: They both generate the same message: "JRebel Config Centre view can only be opened in the JRebel Config Centre perspective!"

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's a bug then. If you run into it again, maybe Reset Perspective (for the JRebel config perspective) would help.

Comment: The way I was able to reproduce this: 1) open the JRebel Config Centre view in another perspective (e.g. Java) -- in there it is normal to display this error. 2) Now switch to JRebel Config Centre perspective -- the view will not be re-initialized and the error stays.

Answer (score 0):

After getting error mentioned in question I was able to get back Jrebel config center by resetting it to default settings, closing and opening it one more time.